# About the Witt ring of a quadratically closed field

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory

> **Theorem 3.2.**
>   $F$ is quadratically closed if and only if $\dim \colon \widehat{W}(F) \to \mathbb{Z}$ is an isomorphism.
>   In this case $W(F) \overset{\sim}{\longrightarrow} \mathbb{Z}_2$.
>
> **Proof.**
>   Suppose $q$ is a form.
>   We have
>   $$
>     q
>   =        \langle a_1 \rangle
>     \perp  \langle a_2 \rangle
>     \dotsb \langle a_n \rangle
>   =        \langle b_1^2 \rangle
>     \perp  \langle b_2^2 \rangle
>     \dotsb \langle b_n^2 \rangle
>   = n \langle 1 \rangle.
> $$
>   So, the map $\dim$ is an isomorphism.
>   Also $q - q' = (\dim q - \dim q') \langle 1 \rangle \in \widehat{W}(F)$.
>   So, $\dim$ is also injective.
>   Note $\mathbb{H} \mapsto 2$.
>
> (Original image [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zNJ9V.png).)

I know that $q$ can be written as squares but then how can they write it as $n \langle 1 \rangle$, is it just saying that it are then $n$ copies of $1$ to induce some map from dimension?

Answer (score 1):

Well, for any $b\in F^*$, we have an obvious isomorphism 
$\langle b^2\rangle\simeq \langle 1\rangle$. Since isomorphisms are compatible with orthogonal sums, we are done.

But maybe you are just confused by the fact that there are typos . This should read:

$q=\langle a_1\rangle\perp\langle a_2\rangle\perp\cdots\perp\langle a_n\rangle=
\langle b_1^2\rangle\perp\langle b_2^2\rangle\perp\cdots\perp\langle b_n^2\rangle=n\langle 1\rangle$, where $n\langle 1\rangle$ means indeed $n$ orthogonal copies of $\langle 1\rangle$

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2889748/about-3-dimensional-quadratic-space

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2923195/about-rational-quadratic-form @